# Parse json using Gson for login system - Application force closes

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm trying to create a login system for my project. I want to create process something like when the register button clicked after filling the form, It's send the data with URL to the API and returns following json string:

```
{
  "result": "OK",
  "message": [
      "Congratulations! You will shortly receive email ."
  ],
  "values": {
      "id": 178964,
      "fname": "", 
      "gender": "female"
  }
}
```

The result string return OK or No only. Now I want to display 'message' in **loginErrorMsg**   when the result return 'OK'. And if the result return Ok then LoginActivity Should be started. But I lost somewhere in parsing the json/gson.

This is the file I created for Register:

```
    public class RegisterActivity  extends Activity{
        private static String URL = "http://api.eample.com/";
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.register);

            final EditText inputFname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerFname);
            final EditText inputLname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerLname);
            final EditText inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
            Button btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
            Button btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLogin);
            final TextView loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

            // Register Button Click event
            btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
                Login login2;
                RadioGroup radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.sex);
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String fname = inputFname.getText().toString();
                    String lname = inputLname.getText().toString();
                    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();

                    // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                    int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    RadioButton radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                    String gender = radioSexButton.getText().toString();
                    System.out.println(fname);
                    //Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    String registerURL = URL +"&user_email="+ email +"&first_name="+ fname +"&last_name="+ lname +"&gender="+ gender;
                    System.out.println(registerURL);

                    if( email.length() == 0) {
                        loginErrorMsg.setText(R.string.empty);
                        //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), R.string.empty, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }else{

                        try {
                            //Create an HTTP client
                            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(registerURL);

                            //Perform the request and check the status code
                            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                                InputStream content = entity.getContent();

                                try {
                                    //Read the server response and attempt to parse it as JSON
                                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);

                                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                                    this.login2 = gson.fromJson(reader, Login.class);

                                    //handlePostsList(posts);
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    //Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON due to: " + ex);
                                    failedLoading();
                                }
                            } else {
                                //Log.e(TAG, "Server responded with status code: " + statusLine.getStatusCode());
                                failedLoading();
                            }
                        } catch(Exception ex) {
                            //Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send HTTP POST request due to: " + ex);
                            failedLoading();
                        }
//To set register message
                    if(login2.getResult().equals("OK")){
                        loginErrorMsg.setText(login2.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                    }


                }
            });

        }
```

Can someone help me to solve the register process? I just want to know how to parse it to get 'message' string data.

Edited:
Changed the login object as following and create values class.

LogCat:

```
09-29 13:05:13.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9428): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 13:05:13.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9428): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-29 13:05:13.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9428):     at com.kabelash.sk.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:105)
09-29 13:05:13.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9428):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
09-29 13:05:13.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9428):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
09-29 13:05:13.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9428):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-29 13:05:13.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9428):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-29 13:05:13.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9428):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-29 13:05:13.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
09-29 13:05:13.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 13:05:13.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-29 13:05:13.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
09-29 13:05:13.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
09-29 13:05:13.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9428):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 13:10:21.380: I/Process(9428): Sending signal. PID: 9428 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Java class `Login` does not represent the structure of the JSON response!

Firstly the field `message` in your JSON is an array (`"message": [...]`), and not a `String`, like in your class `Login`.

Besides, the field `values` in your JSON is an object (`values: {...}`), and not a `ArrayList`, like in your class `Login`.

So, try replacing the attributes in your Login class by:

```
String result;
List<String> message;
Values values;
```

And you'll also need to create a class `Values` with these attributes:

```
long id;
String fname;
String gender;
```

Comment: Now my application force close when I click Register button. Can you help?

Comment: @Kabe, I´m happy it helped! Unfortunately I can't help you with your new problem, since it seems to be related to an android issue, and what I know is Gson... I suggest you to accept this answer and open a new question about the new issue and not about Gson...

Answer (score 0):

When you get the force close message there should be some diagnostic output in LogCat.  For instance it could still be a NullPointerException.  If so you need to look at the line number that is mentioned in logcat and see which line that is in your code.   You can also use the Eclipse debugger to step through the code and see where the problem is occurring.
Gill